# Taking Suggestions For User Management Scheme

Tags: database-design, user-management

I'm beginning work on a web application that will have several distinct user types, example being Registered User, Site Admin, User Admin..etc.  Users may have more than 1 role.

In previous projects, I've been able to manage different user schemas with 3 tables: User, UserRole, User_UserRole.  With this approach, it was relatively easy to manage the M-M relationship between User and UserRole (in User_UserRole table).

However, I don't think this approach will work so nicely in this project for the following reason.  I need to be able to track who (site admin or user admin) approves each user.

I haven't been able to come up with any elegant solution for this, and am looking for some suggestions.  The simpler the better.

Comment: Jim provided the simplest solution. The fact that you couldn't figure that out on your own suggests you might already be in over your head. (That's an observation, not a criticism.) It's kind of like saying, "I'm developing this program, and I've declared five variables, but I need six, and I don't know what to do."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include a `granted_by` column in the `User_UserRole` table that points to the `User` table.